# What kind of pagination can be used in frontend for Microsoft Graph API Calendar List view data in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microsoft-graph-api

Here i am trying to use the Microsoft Graph API data for displaying the meetings in list view the here i got a confusion that how can we basically apply pagination for this kind of Calendar List view .

Graph Api Link :-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-3

Here i  need some suggestion whether i can go with as in response of graph api we are **pagination token** also

1. Vue Virtual /Infinite scroll
2. Tradition pagination like using **next prev button**
3. Token or book mark based pagination

Calendar List view based on Microsoft Graph Api Data:

[image]

and below the sample data set of Microsoft graph api data

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038')/calendarView",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"IiLKjG2I7E+Xv0+ys6MD0wACxWTAzA==\"",
      "id": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OAFRAAgI148WteXAAEYAAAAAIkPFveuwe0ygY4Mfa1RFEQcAIiLKjG2I7E_Xv0_ys6MD0wAAAAABDQAAIiLKjG2I7E_Xv0_ys6MD0wAAGvliqQAAEA==",
      "createdDateTime": "2017-09-08T05:57:46.8659461Z",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-07-11T18:34:44.1945363Z",
      "changeKey": "IiLKjG2I7E+Xv0+ys6MD0wACxWTAzA==",
      "categories": [],
      "transactionId": null,
      "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
      "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
      "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00807E40102F63A77526728D3010000000000000000100000001EE01F52DEEE194B9ABF0A7E79E24D98",
      "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
      "isReminderOn": true,
      "hasAttachments": false,
      "subject": "Market Segment Performance Update",
      "bodyPreview": "You're receiving this message because you're a member of the Product Launch Event group. If you don't want to receive any messages or events from this group, stop following it in your inbox.\r\n\r\nView group conversations   |   View group files",
      "importance": "normal",
      "sensitivity": "normal",
      "isAllDay": false,
      "isCancelled": false,
      "isOrganizer": false,
      "responseRequested": true,
      "seriesMasterId": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAENAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAa_WKpAAA=",
      "showAs": "tentative",
      "type": "occurrence",
      "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OAFRAAgI148WteXAAEYAAAAAIkPFveuwe0ygY4Mfa1RFEQcAIiLKjG2I7E%2BXv0%2Bys6MD0wAAAAABDQAAIiLKjG2I7E%2BXv0%2Bys6MD0wAAGvliqQAAEA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
      "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
      "isOnlineMeeting": false,
      "onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
      "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
      "isDraft": false,
      "recurrence": null,
      "onlineMeeting": null,
      "responseStatus": {
        "response": "notResponded",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-01-02T17:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
      },
      "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-01-02T19:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
      },
      "location": {
        "displayName": "Conf Room Rainier",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueId": "eaa794f1-3007-4444-b592-7590baf6cd90",
        "uniqueIdType": "locationStore"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "displayName": "Conf Room Rainier",
          "locationType": "default",
          "uniqueId": "eaa794f1-3007-4444-b592-7590baf6cd90",
          "uniqueIdType": "locationStore"
        }
      ],
      "attendees": [
        {
          "type": "required",
          "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Product Launch Event",
            "address": "productlaunchevent@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "required",
          "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Lynne Robbins",
            "address": "LynneR@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "required",
          "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Grady Archie",
            "address": "GradyA@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
          }
        }
      ],
      "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "Product Launch Event",
          "address": "productlaunchevent@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For the pagination at the graph end you can use $top query parameter and get the required number of pages, either it may be 10 or 20 and then for the next page you can use the odata.nextlink to get the next items. And also you can use orderby to order them according to the start time of events.

Comment: Ok and do we have any sample ref for vue js or angular ?

Comment: Yes, you can start with this [sample](https://github.com/benc-uk/msal-graph-vue) or [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/master/samples/vue-app). You can go through [this for Angular](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/angular)

Comment: Did my comments helped you?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity yes i got an idea

Comment: Glad to here. Moving this to Answer :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pagination at the graph end you can use $top query parameter and get the required number of pages, either it may be 10 or 20 and then for the next page you can use the odata.nextlink to get the next items. And also you can use orderby to order them according to the start time of events. For more information please go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging).

You can also start with these [samples](https://github.com/benc-uk/msal-graph-vue) or [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/master/samples/vue-app). You can go through [this for Angular](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/angular).